# How to load data from MySql to MS SQL Server database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-migration

I have similar schema in both MySQL and MSSQL Server databases. How can I migrate just the data from MySql to an empty (no data) MSSqlServer database? MSSqlServer DB is empty with just the schema. I could not configure the MySql DB as a linked server (through ODBC) since I don't have DB Admin rights on MSSqlServer. I just have previleges to add data. I explored Sql Server Migration Assistant for MySQL, but I just want to migrate data without touching the schema at the target.
I also noticed that there is a [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) class which helps to programatically migrate data in .NET.
But I need to write code for each table (there are more than 100 tables and 20 GB of data).

What is the most elegant way to do it?

Comment: How do you expect anything to migrate data without knowing about/modifying the schema? It's either going to have to create a new table like the source table, or it's going to have to work out what data goes in which existing field.

Comment: I meant the schema is already prepared. I have information about the schema too. The names of the tables, columns, ordering are all the same. All data types have been adjusted too. (eg ENUM in MySql to varchar()).

Answer (score 0):

[SSMA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42657) might be the easiest. Since you don't wanna use that, you can try using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). You can use it to essentially dump a MySQL db to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the SSMA blog, they update these tools regularly, so check for a later version. [SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) Team's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/)